# Passing Arrays to functions.Format error? C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to create some functions that take empty Arrays and fill them.I get the following format errors.I'm still trying to get to understand pointers but I can't find a way out with this function for hours.What are these format errors?

```
format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]

format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'int *' [-Wformat]
```

Code:

```
int main() {
   int arrayusers[200];
   char arraynames[200][20];
   int n;
   n=0;
   Donate(arrayusers, arraynames,n);
   return 0;
} 

void Donate(int *arrayusers, char (*arraynames)[20],int n)
{
    int b=0;
    printf("Enter Name\n");
    scanf("%s\n", &arraynames[n]);
    printf("Enter ID\n");
    scanf("%d\n", &arrayusers[n]);
    n = n+1;
    for(b=0; b<n; b++){
        printf("%s\n", &arraynames[b]);
        printf("%d\n", &arrayusers[b]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use wonky types like `char (*x)[N]` but instead just the traditional `char **`. Passing pointers means that each string can be sized appropriate to the input, not with all this wasted buffer space for the maximum possible entry size.

Comment: This would also benefit from a simple `struct` that encapsulates the concept of a user name and ID value together.

Comment: You're writing to `arraynames[n]` which looks wrong, that should be one off the end of that array.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Pointers are complicated, just got into C

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
printf("%d\n", &arrayusers[b]);
```

printf wants the integer you want to use in place of %d.  But you're passing a pointer to that integer when you put the & there.  You don't want to give it a pointer to the integer but the actual integer you want used.  Write it like this:

```
printf("%d\n", arrayusers[b]);
```

An array name by itself is just a pointer to the first element in the array.  But once you put [n] behind it you are getting an element from that array which is not a pointer (unless it is an array of pointers) but the actual value of the element in the array.  When you put the & there you're saying to take the address of that number.  It's like you're telling the printf function to put the address of the number you want printed in for %d.  And that makes no sense to the compiler since %d should be a number and not a pointer to a number.

Comment: Good deal. deleting my comment.